Excel - COUNTIFS with multiple match criteria including a date condition
I am trying to pull all records that have been resolved in the last 7 days. I want to count these records by area.
Here is my Excel workbook.
Sheet 1
Row 1 for Titles:      **Area (column A) | State (Column B) | State Changed Date (column C)**
Row 2:                 Development       | In Progress      | 7/8/2024 7:00 AM
Row 3:                 Testing           | Ready            | 7/9/2024 9:16 AM
Row 4:                 Business Analysts | Closed           | 6/30/2024 9:16 AM
Row 5:                 Testing           | Closed           | 7/9/2024 9:16 AM
Row 6:                 Development       | Closed           | 7/8/2024 7:00 AM

Sheet 2
Row 1 for Titles:        **Area (column A) | Total Closed in Last 7 Days (Column B)**
Row 2:                   Development       | 1
Row 3:                   Testing           | 1
Row 4:                   Business Analysts | 0

I want to perform a countifs that does the following:

check sheet 1 column a (Area) for all rows that match Sheet 2 column a (Area).
Once a match is found, count the row only if the date (located in the State Changed Date column of each record) is within the last 7 days

I tried placing this formula in Sheet 2 Column B row 2:
COUNTIFS('Sheet1'!C2:C6,">="&(TODAY()-7),'Sheet1'!A2:A6,A2)

I get #VALUE! in the cell.
I have tried checking the date last but received the same thing.
I can do a COUNTIF('Sheet1'!C2:C6,">="&(TODAY()-7) and I get a correct total for all rows in the last 7 days.  I can do a Countif('Sheet1'!A2:A6,A2) and find all rows in each Area.  I am struggling putting the two together.

Is your issue that you're not locking the cells as you drag the formula down? I did the same formula and was able to get results. COUNTIFS('Sheet1'!$C$2:$C$6,">="&(TODAY()-7),'Sheet1'!$A$2:$A$6,$A$2)

Forgive me, but I'm not sure what you mean.  How would I lock it?

I have $'s in the same formula you have, so in your example you provided unlocked cells, so as you drag the formula down it will update like C3:C7, and now it doesn't highlight the first row anymore, so it may not get matches and produce an error. However if you lock the cells with F4 (so the cell references have $ signs) it will keep referencing the same range as you drag the formula down.

If you're seeing a #value! error it's likely because the ranges in your countifs are not the same height or not lined up with each other.

THAT WAS IT!  Sorry, don't mean to scream but wow, I have looked at this forever and it was so easy.  I am so grateful for you!  I had different end numbers so 2- 6 in one column and 2 - 16 in the other.  I will delete this comment as soon as I figure out how to vote on your answer and close this question out.

Glad to help, sometimes a second set of eyes is all you need on things. :) have a great day

Your issue comes from using relative references that change when dragged or copied down. You may want to learn about the difference between relative and absolute references.
When you put a $ sign into a reference, that part of the reference will be locked and not change when copied or dragged.

=A1 - changes to B1 (dragged across) or A2 (dragged down)
=$A$1 - Locks column and row. Will stay A1, no matter where it is copied or dragged to
=$A1 - Locks column only, stays A1 (dragged across) and changes to A2 (dragged down)
=A$1 - Locks row only, changes to B1 (dragged across) and stays A1 (dragged down)

If you want to copy your formula down and ensure it still references the original range, change the references to absolute references.
=COUNTIFS('Sheet1'!$C$2:$C$6,">="&(TODAY()-7),'Sheet1'!$A$2:$A$6,$A$2)


Instead of the last $A$2, It must be either A2 or $A2.

Count With Multi-Column Criteria

You didn't lock the cells.
You didn't implement the 'Closed' criterion.

Legacy Excel
A Simple COUNTIFS (B2 Copy Down)
=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$6,$A2,Sheet1!$B$2:$B$6,"Closed",Sheet1!$C$2:$C$6,">="&(TODAY()-7))


MS365
Hard-Coded (B2 Spills Down)
=LET(s_data,Sheet1!A2:C6,s_area_col,1,s_state_col,2,s_date_col,3,
        d_area,A2:A6,d_state,"Closed",d_max_age,7,
    sa,CHOOSECOLS(s_data,s_area_col),
    ss,CHOOSECOLS(s_data,s_state_col),
    sd,CHOOSECOLS(s_data,s_date_col),
    d_min,TODAY()-d_max_age,
    BYROW(d_area,LAMBDA(r,
        SUM((sa=r)*(ss=d_state)*(sd>=d_min)))))

Additional Cells (E2, E3) Usually Drop-Downs (B2 Spills Down)
=LET(s_data,Sheet1!A2:C6,s_area_col,1,s_state_col,2,s_date_col,3,
        d_area,A2:A6,d_state,E2,d_max_age,E3,
    sa,CHOOSECOLS(s_data,s_area_col),
    ss,CHOOSECOLS(s_data,s_state_col),
    sd,CHOOSECOLS(s_data,s_date_col),
    d_min,TODAY()-d_max_age,
    BYROW(d_area,LAMBDA(r,
        SUM((sa=r)*(ss=d_state)*(sd>=d_min)))))

Retrieving Unique Rowlabels (G2 Spills Across)
=LET(s_data,Sheet1!A2:C6,s_area_col,1,s_state_col,2,s_date_col,3,
        d_state,E2,d_max_age,E3,
    sa,CHOOSECOLS(s_data,s_area_col),
    ss,CHOOSECOLS(s_data,s_state_col),
    sd,CHOOSECOLS(s_data,s_date_col),
    da,UNIQUE(sa),
    d_min,TODAY()-d_max_age,
    t,BYROW(da,LAMBDA(r,
        SUM((sa=r)*(ss=d_state)*(sd>=d_min)))),
    r,HSTACK(da,t),
    r)


Replace the last r with any other variable to see what it holds.

In H1 e.g.:
="Total "&E2&" (Last "&E3&" Days)"

